# PHP odbc driver as shared extension

Tags: php, linux, build, odbc, yocto

I am using php with version 5.6.31 in embedded project with yocto-linux as operating system. What I wants to do is have odbc driver as shared library instead of hard-link. Reason for this is I have 2 different use-cases with use PHP with one requiring custom-odbc-driver. Since I am building it for embedded domain due to space concern I doesn't wants to add it statically in PHP binary. There is guide available to [compile php extension as shared](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_extensions.html).

My questing is can we have odbc driver as shared library? guide mentioned that not all but few extension can be shared. I tried building PHP with config flag `--with-custom-odbc=shared` but it failed with fatal error:

> odbc.h : No such file or directory .

`--with-custom-odbc` flag required path with odbc installation. If we can have odbc driver as shared library then which config flag should be used to describe it?

Comment: Well, [there's this](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/IODBCPHPHOWTO) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php).  Basically, you build with a link (which might be static or dynamic) to the ODBC driver *manager* (either iODBC or UnixODBC), which handles the dynamic loading of whatever ODBC *drivers*.

Answer (score 4):

First install `unixODBC-devel`:

```
$ sudo yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel

$ sudo repoquery --installed -l unixODBC-devel
/usr/include/autotest.h
/usr/include/odbcinst.h
/usr/include/odbcinstext.h
/usr/include/sql.h
/usr/include/sqlext.h
/usr/include/sqltypes.h
/usr/include/sqlucode.h
/usr/include/unixodbc_conf.h
/usr/include/unixodbc_conf_x86_64.h
/usr/include/uodbc_extras.h
/usr/include/uodbc_stats.h

$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: ~/.odbc.ini

$ odbcinst -q -d
[PostgreSQL]
[MySQL]
```

And then configure `PHP` with `--with-unixODBC`:

```
./configure --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr
```

When `unixODBC` is not available as package, it can also be built from [source code](http://www.unixodbc.org):

```
$ wget http://www.unixodbc.org/unixODBC-2.3.7.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf unixODBC-2.3.7.tar.gz
$ cd unixODBC-2.3.7
$ ./configure --help

$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

There's even a Qt front-end for it: [unixodbc-gui-qt](https://sourceforge.net/p/unixodbc-gui-qt/code/HEAD/tree/).